# .HTACCESS RewriteRule for 2 Domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

I have two domains, which content is in the same file directory:

```
http://www.alpha.com/

DIR: /var/www/alpha.com/
```

and

```
http://www.beta.com/

DIR: /var/www/beta.com/
```

**I want to do the following thing:**

When user goes to

```
http://www.alpha.com/beta/
```

he should see the content of

```
http://www.beta.com
```

and by going e.g. to

```
http://www.alpha.com/beta/index.php?a=3&b=2
```

he should see the content of

```
http://www.beta.com/index.php?a=3&b=2
```

and so on.

**How can I manage that with htaccess?**

**And in which directory should I place that?**

I thought about that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/beta/(var1)$

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://beta.com/%1
```

But it doesnt work. And I'm not good in regular expressions.

Thank you for every answer!

Answer (score 2):

Put the below `.htaccess` file into `/var/www/alpha.com/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/beta/?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://beta.com [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/beta/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://beta.com/%1 [L]
```

- question mask `?`: makes the preceding token optional
- `L` flag: means the last rule

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the `.htaccess` file?  If not, using VirtualHosts in the `httpd.conf` file might be better than a rewrite.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/alpha.com/
ServerName www.alpha.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/beta.com
ServerName www.beta.com
</VirtualHost>
```